# Rescale Scene or Mesh after loading with Sceneloader

Tags: three.js

I'm not sure why I cannot rescale my scene after loading with sceneLoader.
I have a simple box that I created and exported from blender as js file.
I tried rescaling the entire result scene before and after. I even looped over the mesh objects and tried rescaling but the scale.set has no affect.

```
var callbackFinished = function ( result ) {
   result.scene.scale.set(10,10,10)
   scene.add(result.scene);
}
loader.load( "box.js", callbackFinished );
```

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: can you share your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ editor

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to solve it. When loading my model with SceneLoader, the verticesNeedUpdate property is set to false. So I had to set all the mesh verticesNeedUpdate to true for the scale to work.